# How to store spring boot app's build name and version in sentry error log?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, sentry

Sentry stores a lot of useful data. I recently encountered a problem where I was supposed to add build version and name to every error log passed to Sentry.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a junior dev and this is my first time sharing some knowledge and I hope it would be useful.

After a lot of research and tries I came up with solutions and decided to gather what I learned in one post.
So - preconditions:
My app uses spring boot 2.2.9 and is configured to use `logback`, it also has a cool plugin - gradle-git-properties, which stores essential build info in a build folder in `META-INF/build-info.properties`. During build it creates `build-info.properties` file in a build folder containing

```
build.name=myApp
build.version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

`build.gradle` contains these lines:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.2.9.RELEASE"
    //...
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.2.2"
    //...
}
```

These properties can be used in logback configuration file `logback-spring.xml` as follows:

```
<property resource="META-INF/build-info.properties" />
<property scope="context" name="buildVersion" value="${build.version}"/>
<property scope="context" name="buildName" value="${build.name}"/>
```

Those to fields `buildVersion` and `buildName` will have respective values attached to each sentry issue.